# Java: Lock not working as intended

Tags: java

The lock in my code is not working as intended. I fairly new at using locks basically followed the example i was given.

code:

```
public void run(){
    int counter =0;
    EachLink nextLink=null;

    crawlStarterLock.lock();
    try{
        while (index<LIMIT){
            nextLink = theLinks.getNext(); //get the next item 

            if(nextLink == null)
            {
               sleep(DELAY);

               System.out.println(counter);
               counter++;
               index++;
               //break;

            }
            else{

                try{
                    Thread tr = new Crowler(nextLink,theLinks); //creates and runs a new thread writing the links to an html file.
                    tr.start();
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    counter++;
                }

                finally{
                    index++;
                }
            }   
        }   
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){}//exception
    finally
    {
      crawlStarterLock.unlock();//unlocks the lock when operation is finished
      System.out.println("Hello");

    }
```

Lock object is created in the constructor

```
crawlStarterLock = new ReentrantLock();
```

My index starts from 0 and Limit is set to 100
The output when i run this program shows a race condition between 2 counters.
My understanding is that if the object is lock none other should be able to access thus counter should print 0-100 then 0-100 for another instance of this run method()?
So am i using the lock here incorrectly

Comment: `Lock object is created in the constructor` What constructor? Make sure that they use the same lock and that you don't just make a new lock for each thread

Comment: oh i have my private Lock crawlStarterLock; as an instance field of the object and is created in the constructor so it would seem like the lock a new lock is being created each time, you are right. Where would i initialize my lock so that it would only be created once for this object

Comment: Try making the lock static or making one outside and pass it in for each thread, depending on your needs.